# How to Allocate Random Jobs to List of Agents in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to write a script that will allow me to allocate random jobs to 7 different agents. The following are my 2 tables:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs;

CREATE TABLE `Jobs` (
     `Job_id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     `Start_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `End_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `Ref_no` int NOT NULL
    ) ;

INSERT INTO Jobs(Job_id,Start_Date, End_Date, Ref_no) VALUES
(1,'2018-09-01','2021-08-31',123456789),
(2,'2019-10-03','2020-10-02',987654321),
(3,'2020-11-01','2021-10-02',543210123),
(4,'2020-12-01','2022-11-30',481216181),
(5,'2018-04-01','2020-03-31',246810121),
(6,'2019-05-30','2020-05-29',369121518),
(7,'2019-11-01','2020-10-31',581114179);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS agents;

CREATE TABLE `Agents` (
`Agent_id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
`Agent_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
) ;

INSERT INTO Agents(Agent_id, Agent_Name) VALUES
(1,'Humpty'),
(2,'Mickey'),
(3,'Minnie'),
(4,'Daffy'),
(5,'Ellie'),
(6,'Jack'),
(7,'Jill');
```

Now what I would like to do is write a script that would randomly allocate the jobs across the 7 agents. Would really appreciate it if somebody could advise on how I could start this off.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY RAND()` - and please test all code before posting.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which kind of "script" are you looking for- something running with pure MySQL queries?

Comment: It's very convenient that you have 7 jobs and 7 agents - is it really representative of your problem though?

Comment: Hi P Salmon, the above is an example of the dataset, the data that will be split will be an equal amount across the 7 agents so the agents is the right amount. The amount of data when I run this against the data when it comes in will vary.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.x you can combine `RAND()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` to associate random rows. For example:

```
select *  
from (
  select *, row_number() over(order by rand()) as rn
  from `Jobs`
) j
join (
  select *, row_number() over(order by rand()) as rn
  from `Agents`
) a on j.rn = a.rn
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gpRfTwjJ63SX5PftU6dkz/2).

Comment: Thank you guys, will try the replies and respond back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method for versions of MySQL prior to 8.0...

```
SELECT x.*
     , MOD(@i:=@i+1,7) + 1 i -- where '7' is the number of agents.
  FROM
     ( SELECT j.*
         FROM jobs j
        ORDER
           BY RAND()
     ) x
  JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) vars
 ORDER
    BY i;
```

Sample output:

```
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+------+
| Job_id | Start_Date | End_Date   | Ref_no    | i    |
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+------+
|      5 | 2018-04-01 | 2020-03-31 | 246810121 |    1 |
|      3 | 2020-11-01 | 2021-10-02 | 543210123 |    2 |
|      1 | 2018-09-01 | 2021-08-31 | 123456789 |    3 |
|      7 | 2019-11-01 | 2020-10-31 | 581114179 |    4 |
|      4 | 2020-12-01 | 2022-11-30 | 481216181 |    5 |
|      6 | 2019-05-30 | 2020-05-29 | 369121518 |    6 |
|      2 | 2019-10-03 | 2020-10-02 | 987654321 |    7 |
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+------+
```